# How can I add a jQuery UI icon to a dynamically generated button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, icons

When downloading jQuery UI you get a stylesheet for whatever theme was selected, as well as several image files containing icons.  I've figured out how to add an icon to a single `<button>` element, but I have a situation where I'm dynamically generating buttons in a grid (jqGrid) and want to use these icons.  So, say I want to use this icon from the CSS file:

```
.ui-icon-trash { background-position: -176px -96px; }
```

Then, I add the buttons to the grid by handling the `gridComplete` event:

```
gridComplete: function () {
    var ids = $("#myGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var deleteButton = "<button type='button' style='height: 22px;width: 20px;' title='Delete' onclick=deleteRow(" + ids[i] + ")></button>";
        $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { DeleteButton: deleteButton });
    }
}
```

I've tried using a class in the button tag, for example, `deleteRowButton`, and then using jQuery like this:

```
$(".deleteRowButton").button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-trash'
    },
    text: false
});
```

But this doesn't work.  What do I have to do to get my buttons to have this icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that your code with `$(".deleteRowButton").button({icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-trash'}, text: false});` didn't worked because you placed it in the wrong place. If you create the `<button class='deleteRowButton' ...>` inside of `gridComplete` you should make the call `$(".deleteRowButton").button(...)` also **inside of `gridComplete`** directly after the code which you posted:

```
gridComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this), ids = $this.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), l = ids.length,
        i, deleteButton;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        deleteButton = "<button type='button' style='height:22px;width:20px;'" +
            " class='deleteRowButton' title='Delete' onclick=deleteRow(" +
            ids[i] + ")></button>";
        $this.jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { DeleteButton: deleteButton });
    }
    $(".deleteRowButton").button({
        icons: {
            primary: 'ui-icon-trash'
        },
        text: false
    });
}
```

see [the first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/trashicon.htm).

The small problem exists in the performance of the above approach. Using `setRowData` you make changes on the page. Every change on the page follow recalculation of positions of **all other elements existing on the page**. So to improve performance it's recommended to reduce the number of changes on the grid. So the better way is the usage of [custom formattrer](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter). The new version of the code will be practically exactly so easy as the previous one. You just need to define `formatter` as function:

```
{ name: 'DeleteButton', width: 20,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options) {
        return "<button type='button' class='deleteRowButton' " +
            "style='height: 22px;width: 20px;' title='Delete'></button>";
    }},
```

and reduce the code of `gridComplete` or `loadComplete` to

```
gridComplete: function () {
    $(".deleteRowButton").button({
        icons: {
            primary: 'ui-icon-trash'
        },
        text: false
    }).click(function (e) {
        var $tr = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow");
        alert("the row with id=" + $tr.attr("id") + " need be deleted");
    });
}
```

In your original code the method `deleteRow` must be *global* (it should be defined on the top level). The new code can use just `click` event handler. See [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/trashicon1.htm).

By the way you don't really need to bind every `<button>` to `click` event handler. As well known if there are no `click` event handler on the button the [event bubbling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow) will take place. So instead of binding `click` event handler every time on loading and reloading of the grid one can just define **once** the corresponding event handler on the whole grid body. In other words you can use `onCellSelect` callback. the usage is very comfortable because the `rowid` and the index of the column of the clicked cell are already calculated. Moreover per 4-th parameter `e` of the `onCellSelect` callback you can access to the event handler where `e.tagret` is the DOM element of the clicked `<button>`. So you can replace the above code of `gridComplete` to the following code:

```
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("button.deleteRowButton").length > 0) {
        alert("the row with id=" + rowid + " need be deleted");
    }
},
gridComplete: function () {
    $(".deleteRowButton").button({
        icons: {
            primary: 'ui-icon-trash'
        },
        text: false
    });
}
```

In the way you can more improve the performance and reduce a little the memory used for the page. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/trashicon2.htm) shows the last code live. In the most cases you don't need to use constructs like `$(e.target).closest("button.deleteRowButton").length > 0`. Instead of that you can just verify the column index `iCol`. If you need you can test the column name instead. You can use

```
$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel")[iCol].name
```

to convert the `iCol` to the corresponding column name.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest switching from 'button' to 'input type="button"'
You should be able to use the background image in CSS to set an icon.  Your grid complete function would look something like this:

```
gridComplete: function () {    
var ids = $("#myGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');    
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {    
    var deleteButton = "<input type='button' class='HasIcon' style='height: 22px;width: 20px;' title='Delete' onclick=deleteRow(" + ids[i] + ")/>";    
    $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { DeleteButton: deleteButton });    
}
```

}

and your CSS would look like this:

```
#myGrid input[type=button].HasIcon
{
    background-image: url(/* icon location */);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px; /* slightly longer than your icon */
}
```

You won't need to use jquery to apply the icon, since CSS will do that for you.  The magic of CSS triumphs again!  :-)

Comment: Thanks Frankie.  Since the icon is actually part of the larger image that has all the icons in it, what would I specify for my `background-image` URL?  Here's a link to the icon set: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/tests/static/icons.html

Comment: Hmmmm, that could be a little trickier.  What you'll need to do is specify the background offset like so:

background-position: -176px -96px;

Comment: Hmmm, that won't clip the size down though, so you end up with all the other icons showing.  You might be able to get away with a pseudo-selector called "Before" but I don't think that IE8/7/6 will support it, but that would mean that you'd have to choose something other than a button, since buttons can't contain other elements (maybe an anchor tag would be good).  See http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/