# How to show a column in the grid and hide it in the view dialog

Tags: jqgrid

I've used the information on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976396/how-can-i-add-a-jquery-ui-icon-to-a-dynamically-generated-button) to add a button to my grid and it works great. But I don't want that button to be displayed if the user opens that row in the view dialog. How can I hide this item in the view dialog?

I know that I can hide a column in the grid and then display it in the view dialog by using this syntax in the column definition:

```js
, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true },
```

But I see no way of reversing these options. I've played with different combinations of the above options, and the `hidedlg` option, but have had no luck.

To clarify, we are using the [free version of jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote about "the view dialog" in the title of your question. Do you really mean View dialog or Edit dialog? View Dialog will be shown if you click on "View" button of navigator bar, but the button exists only if `view: true` option is used in `navGrid`. In the case you can use `viewable: false` property in the column.

If you want to hide the column in Edit dialog, then you can use `editable: "hidden"` property in the column (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function)). The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ho803dvq/ uses properties

```js
viewable: false, editable: "hidden"
```

in the last `note` column. The column will be shown in the grid, but the column is not visible in either View or Edit dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Guriddo jqGrid you can use the option **viewable** in colModel. Set this option to false in order to show the field in grid, but not in view form.

See the documentation for [this here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#view-grid-row)